# Trying to submit a form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble submitting a form. I have filled it out. The form starts like:

```
<form action="?&amp;v=b&amp;fv=b&amp;" name="f" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

I have tried variants of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form[name="f"]').submit();
});
```

Could someone advise me on some other techniques to post the form back to the server?

edit: sorry I truncated part of the action string for the sake of brevity. I didn't want to over complicate things but I am working with phantom js to develop a test and I am trying to enter a password protected website , fill out the form and submit it programatically. I've been able to get the first 2 things working, but I can't submit the form.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to trigger a submit to a different querystring on pageload, but wouldn't that just create a loop ?

Comment: I agree with @adeneo! Why do you wanna submit form on page load event?

Comment: It might not create a loop if the server redirects to a different page depending on the POST vars being there

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to post those values back to the server? It is confusing what you want to do.

```
<form action="" name="f" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="aa" value="b" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbc" value="c" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="f"]').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this this:

```
document.forms[formName].submit();
```

Comment: I tried:function() {
   console.log('click send');
   page.injectJs("jquery.js");
      page.evaluate(function() {
 $(document.forms["f"]).submit();  - but does not work

Comment: Above method i posted doesn't requires jquery. However jsfiddle of what you done will clear the issue here.

Comment: I'm sorry Eez, are you asking me to post a JS fiddle of the code?

Comment: Above code you posted submits form on document load only, which sounds very unclear why you submitting form on document load. Jsfiddle of form html and on which event you want to submit form would help to understand.