# Trying to click submit button with jquery in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I am working with phantom js to develop a test and I am trying to enter a password protected website , fill out the form and submit it programatically. I've been able to get the first 2 things working, but I can't submit the form.

There is an included send button which looks like:

```
<input type="submit" name="nv_b_send" value="Send">
```

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('input[value=Send]').each(function () {
        $(this).click();
     console.log('    button clicked    ');

});
```

I'm getting "button clicked" included in the output so I believe that jquery is finding the correct element but that the click is not working. What is the best way to get the click event to occur?

Comment: Hey how about a followup on this other question before you ask a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690703/trying-to-submit-a-form-with-jquery

Comment: Sorry Joe, I'm trying to break down the question into smaller chunks, and there are 2 potential approaches that I can see. 1 - Submit form, 2 - Press submit button. This is the second. - Bill